# Show inequality for a function bounded by nondecreasing functions on a ball

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $v:E\to[1,\infty)$ be continuous, $$\rho_r(x,y):=\inf_{\substack{\gamma\:\in\:C^1([0,\:1],\:E)\\ \gamma(0)\:=\:x\\ \gamma(1)\:=\:y}}\int_0^1v^r\left(\gamma(t)\right)\left\|\gamma'(t)\right\|_E\:{\rm d}t\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E\;\;\;\text{for }r>0$$ and $v_i:[0,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$ be continuous and nondecreasing with $$v_1(\left\|x\right\|_E)\le v(x)\le v_2(\left\|x\right\|_E)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\tag1$$ and $$av_2(a)\le C_1v_1^\theta(a)\;\;\;\text{for all }a>0\tag2$$ for some $C_1\ge0$ and $\theta\ge1$.

Now let $r\in(0,1)$, $k,\delta>0$ and $x,y\in E$ with $\rho_1(x,y)<k$ and $\rho_r(x,y)\ge\delta$. Assume $$\left\|x\right\|_E>c:=k+v_1^{-1}\left(\left(\frac\delta k\right)^{\frac1{r-1}}\right)\tag3.$$

> How can we show that $$kv^{r-1}(z)\le\frac\delta k\tag4$$ for all $z\in E$ with $\left\|x-z\right\|_E\le k$?

By the reverse triangle inequality, we clearly have $$v_1^{-1}\left(\left(\frac\delta k\right)^{\frac1{r-1}}\right)=c-k<\left\|x\right\|_E-\left\|x-z\right\|_E\le\left\|z\right\|_E\tag5$$ for all $z\in E$ with $\left\|x-z\right\|_E\le k$. And by $(1)$ and $r-1\le 0$, $$v^{r-1}(z)\le v_1^{r-1}(\left\|z\right\|_E)=v_1^r(\left\|z\right\|_E)v_1^{-1}(\left\|z\right\|_E)\tag6.$$

I don't know whether it's relevant or irrelevant for the desired conclusion that $\rho_1(x,y)<k$ and $\rho_r(x,y)\ge\delta$. Maybe the only thing we need is $(2)$ and $\frac\delta k$ could be replaced by any constant. But if not, please note $$\rho_s(x,y)\le\left\|x-y\right\|_Ev_2^s(\left\|x-y\right\|_E+\left\|y\right\|_E)\;\;\;\text{for all }s>0\tag7$$ and $$\rho_r(x,y)\le v_1^{r-1}(0)\rho_1(x,y).\tag8$$ Note that $(8)$ implies that $$\frac\delta k\le v_1^{r-1}(0)\tag9$$ and hence (since $r-1<0$) $$v_1(0)\le\left(\frac\delta k\right)^{\frac1{r-1}};\tag{10}$$ otherwise $x$ and $y$ as given cannot exist.